# Creating dynamic partition in Range partitioning

Tags: sql, database, oracle, partitioning

I have below scenario.
Suppose I have a table which has 3 partition. one is for `20190201` next is `20190202` and one is for `20190210`.
I have been given requirement. whichever date we pass automatic partition should be created.
so if I am using dynamic sql I am able to create partition after the max partition for eg `20190211`. but if I want to create partition for `20190205` it is giving error. 
Is there anyway to create the partition at run time without data loss even when max partition exist.
We have been told not to create interval partitioning

Comment: What are you being told not to use interval partitioning?

Comment: Use `alter table ... split partition`. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1008028)

Comment: We can not use interval partitioning because we are using older version of DB

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple.

while creating the table itself use interval partition on the date column. 
you can choose the partition interval as hour/day/month whichever you like.

so any time you insert a new data to the table based on the date value the data will go to correct partition or create a new partition.
use the below syntax in your table while creating..

```
partition by range ( date_col )
interval ( NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day') )
( partition p1 values less then ( date '2016-01-01' ))
```